# How do I generate a list of data sources for multiple PBI Reports with data from SQL Server or Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi

I have several hundred powerBI reports that point to different views / tables in a SQL server data warehouse and an Azure cloud environment.

Is there a way for me to generate a list of the views and tables that these reports query without having to go through the query editor for each report one by one?

According to some old forum posts Microsoft Purview isn't compatible with SQL server or AZ for exactly what I need. I don't know if that's still accurate but I'm having a hard time finding that information in the microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Since your answer is looking for automatic approach, it should be done programmatically.

With the Power BI REST API, you can query all reports in a Workspace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-report-in-group#report

After you get an answer, you can loop on every report and get the dataset id of the report (inside the report object of the answer).

Then you can query the datasources themselves itself, also with REST API. For this call toy will need the dataset id you got from the previous call:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-datasources-in-group

Finally the answer of this call will get you the datasource name, connection string and other needed information.

Comment: But it doesn't return the Tables/Views, only the connection string